# Batchfile not working through php (timeout)

Tags: php, batch-file

I have here a batch file that works when i double click it. 
However, running this batch file through php launches notepad and just kills it right away.

```
START C:\Windows\NOTEPAD.EXE
timeout /t 60 
taskkill /im "NOTEPAD.EXE" /f
```

Is there any reason why timeout doesn't work? Any help is appreciated. Thanks!

Edit: I have refactored the code but pause also gets skipped.

```
START C:\Windows\NOTEPAD.EXE

..\..\..\Windows\System32\timeout.exe /t 1000
pause
taskkill /im "NOTEPAD.EXE" /f
```

Comment: Strange. Notepad, Timeout and Taskkill are all located in the SYSTEM32 directory. The only thing I can think of is it's finding another program named timeout within the system path variable before it finds timeout.exe in SYSTEM32.  Try giving it the full path to timeout.exe.

Comment: How do you invoke the batch file in php? timeout does not support input redirection and will terminate immediately. That could also be the issue.

Comment: Hey @Squashman . I have refactored the code to be like this. It skips even the pause command.

Comment: @sst
My php page has a button that redirects to another php page containing `exec("batFile");`

Comment: I am baffled as to why you would use the fully qualified path to `Notepad` but use a relative path for `TIMEOUT`?  I would put the `NOBREAK` option in there as well. `C:\Windows\System32\timeout.exe /t 1000 /nobreak`

Comment: @Squashman I used both fully qualified path earlier but missed a back slash on ``TIMEOUT`` and got an error and used the relative path instead. looking back, I should have paid more attention. Thank you very much for helping, it is much appreciated.

Comment: So did you retest with: `C:\Windows\System32\timeout.exe /t 60 /nobreak`

Comment: What is it with `..\..\..\Windows\System32\timeout.exe`? It seems you have a tendency to use fully qualified absolute path for timeout. Just use `C:\Windows\System32\timeout.exe` or better use `%SystemRoot%\system32\timeout.exe`. Anyway it doesn't matter since the `pause` is ineffective and that means the input is redirected and `timeout.exe` will not run with redirected input and `/nobreak` switch can not change that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using a PING timeout to see if it fixes the problem with delay..

`PING -n 60 127.0.0.1>nul`

https://ss64.com/nt/timeout.html

Timeout will pause command execution for a number of seconds, after which it continues without requiring a user keystroke. If the user does press a key at any point, execution will resume immediately.

A delay can also be produced by the PING command with a loopback address, there is a delay of 1 second between each consecutive ping.

In tests PING consumes less processor time than Sleep.exe or Timeout.exe, this allows other processes to run in the background. The PING command can only be interrupted with Ctrl-C. Source: Clay Calvert (usenet 2001.)

Comment: You could specify `timeout /T 1 /NOBREAK` to not accept key-strokes (except Ctrl+C)...